# Defensive copying of Number subclass

Tags: java, generics

Please consider the following example:

```
public final class ImmutableWrapper<T extends Number> {

    private final T value;

    public ImmutableWrapper(T value) {
        // a subclass of Number may be mutable
        // so, how to defensively copying the value?
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        // the same here: how to return a copy?
        return value;
    }
}
```

In order to make this class immutable, I must defensively copy any mutable parameter passed to the constructor and create copies of internal mutable objects returned by public methods.

Is this possible? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Isn't it simpler to state in the javadoc that if the number is mutated the behaviour of the class is undefined in a multi threaded context?

Comment: @assylias For example, I saw in Guava's [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) a warning about passing mutable objects to the constructor in the javadoc. Anyway this is my last option.

Comment: unless you are afraid of malicious code messing up with your code, that is a perfectly reasonable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all `Number`s are [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) you can create copies by `serializing/deserializing` them.

Maybe you can use apache commons-lang's [`SerializationUtils.clone(Serializable)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html).

```
public final class ImmutableWrapper<T extends Number> {

    private final T value;

    public ImmutableWrapper(T value) {
        // a subclass of Number may be mutable
        // so, how to defensively copying the value?
        this.value = SerializationUtils.clone(value);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        // the same here: how to return a copy?
        return  SerializationUtils.clone(value);
    }
}
```

or if you want to implement it by yourself take a look at:

- [Cloning of Serializable and Non-Serializable Java Objects](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/cloning-of-serializable-and-non.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the object. So your code would look like:

```
public final class ImmutableWrapper<T extends Number> {
    private final T value;

    public ImmutableWrapper(T value) {
        this.value = value.clone();
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: But `T extends Number` and a `java.lang.Number` has no public method `clone`. How do you compile this example?

Comment: And Number does not implement Cloneable either.

Comment: Just pasted this into eclipse. The compiler is not happy about `value.clone()`, since `clone()` is not visible on `Object`.

Comment: What about cloning by the [cloning](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/) library? Any drawbacks?

Comment: @Paolo Go with Rene Links answer above. He is right, the clone method is protected.

Comment: @mikea I understood the issue about the clone method. I'm just wondering if using the [cloning](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/) library (which doesn't rely on Java's `Clonable` interface, but exploit reflection to make copies of objects) could be another good option.

Comment: @Paulo it's possible an option but may not be as performant as the SerializationUtils. Reflection is a notorious cpu hog.